# Is this free indirect speech?

Tags: discourse-analysis, speech-acts

> The next morning, when the alarm went off, he wanted to keep his eyes
> closed and keep on with the dream he was having. *Something about a
> farmhouse. And there was a waterfall in there, too. Someone, he didn't
> know who, was walking along the road carrying something. Maybe it was
> a picnic hamper. He was not made uneasy by the dream. In the dream,
> there seemed to exist a sense of well-being.* Finally, he rolled over
> and pushed something to stop the buzzing. ("Fever" by Raymond Carver)

I'm studying forms of speech representation in literature (indirect speech, direct speech, free indirect speech). People who studied narratology, specifically, "discourse representation" would be able to identify this. I'm new to Stack Exchange and I don't know where to find them.

Comment: You need to define free indirect speech. I have never heard that term. That paragraph doesn't really contain spoken language. However, speech is a very broad term. Generally here, you need to show some effort at research or in your thinking.

Comment: Presumably you have access to the definition of “free indirect speech”. Rewrite the above, telling us what part of the quoted text you believe qualifies as free indirect speech, and why. Then formulate a question on the aspects your are unsure of.

Comment: My former colleague Michael Toolan has worked on this; check e.g. his "Language in LIterature: An Introduction to Stylistics".

Comment: @Lambie it’s a common term in narratology. If you don’t know it and can’t be bothered to look it up (there’s an extensive Wikipedia entry), you don’t need to comment either.

Comment: @Keelan Usually, OPs are supposed to show some effort...

Comment: @Lambie yes, and I have upvoted Segorian's comment, but that is not what I was referring to.

Comment: @Keelan Well, perhaps much more literature and structuralism than US linguistics. Wikipedia: Narratology is the study of narrative and narrative structure and the ways that these affect human perception.[1] It is an anglicisation of French narratologie, coined by Tzvetan Todorov (Grammaire du Décaméron, 1969). Actually, I knew it in French only.